# Getting types from NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

It's my first time using core data. I'm trying to use it to store basic info about my user (if he's logged in through parse.com). So far so good with writing to core data, however, I'm struggling to get the data back. I'm able to print out the data as a `[NSManagedObject]`, but I can't get the data into the different types ( `String`, `Bool`, and `UIImage`). How can I do this?

**Saving Data**

```
func saveUser(username : String, proPic : UIImage?){


        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //2
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User",
            inManagedObjectContext:
            managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        //3
        person.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
        person.setValue(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        person.setValue(proPic, forKey: "profilePic")

        //4
        var error: NSError?
        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

**Getting Data Back**

```
        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"UserInfo")

        //3
        var error: NSError?



        let fetchedResults =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
            error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
```

Comment: You appear to be saving as "User" entity and trying to fetch as "UserInfo" entity. Using the same entity to save and fetch from might be a start.

Comment: Good eye for spotting that, the getting data back is just some sample code I wrote, it's not really what I'm working with

Answer (score 0):

You can use `valueForKey` similar way you used `setValue` before. Then you need to deal with the fact that it returns `AnyObject`.

Another option is to generate custom `NSManagedObject` subclass. Select your entity in the model editor and in the top menu go to Editor->Create NSManagedObjectSubclass... It will navigate you through the steps. Once you have that, you will have custom class with properties of appropriate type for each entity attribute.